# Is it possible to use a multiValued field in geodist

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial

I have the following field-definition in the schema.xml (Solr 4.1):

```
<field name="locationCoordinates" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Now I want to basically do the following query:

Filter for the coordinates wheter they are in a given distance of a geographic point (this part already works) and return the distance to the nearest point.

Or in the real life situation:

We have Articles. Every Article is available at multiple stores (only saved as geo-location) (N:N, but we only have the Article modelled with Solr). Now I want to query for Articles that are in range of a given point and if they are also return the distance to that point.

How can I accomplish that using Solr-Queries?

Comment: or do i have to normalize the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is a geographic sort, right?

To achieve the same, you've got to use custom sort feature in the Lucene.

If sorting by score, id, field is not sufficient, Lucene lets you implement custom sorting mechanism by providing your own subclass of FieldComparatorSource abstract base class.

Steps:

1) Sort object accepts FieldComparatorSource type instance during instantiation.

2) Extend FieldComparatorSource

3) You've to load the coordinates using FieldCache within the FieldComparatorSource in setNextReader()

4) For each document, you can compute the distance from your origin and return one of {-1, 0, 1}

Actually, the whole example is given in following link. But you've to register for a free trial.

[Link to Custom sort in the book Lucene in Action 2](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/seo/9781933988177/extending-search/ch06lev1sec1)

Comment: yes i want to do geographic sort, indeed. I will try that out tomorrow   :)

Comment: glad that I got it right. Then my link should solve your problem. Incorporating that into Solr as a plugin should not trouble you either.

Comment: is there a more specific class that I can extend of in order to use it with location_rpt?

Comment: I am just realizing that this isn't exactly what I want to do. I want to get the nearest geo location from one document and use that one to sort. I don't think that I can do that with the stuff you mentioned.

Comment: Please could you confirm following : 1) There's a document which is the query, you wanna get the nearest geolocation from that document (so the document has the coordinates stored?); 2) Once you get the nearest geolocation, you are planning to sort the results; results..to which query?

Comment: I will try to answer if you could come up with an example. The article-example description didn't help me understand the entire use-case.

Comment: Sorry my friend. I don't really need it anymore. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: hi @MartinBraun, I think I do have exactly same problem, how did you resolve this ? appreciate any help

Comment: @egig: This was ages ago... Sorry, I do not remember the fix. However, you can try to explain your problem to me and I will try my best at helping you :)